# Determinar la función sintáctica

Tags: subjuntivo, sintaxis

> Él agarrándose con sumo cuidado de la hiedra (o de la parra salvaje, o
>   de las lianas, o de lo que diablos **fueran** aquellos tallos), empezó a
>   subir.

Si lo he entendido bien, aquí se trata del subjuntivo con antecedente desconocido. 
¿Pero qué es esta estructura interna desde el punto de vista sintáctico? ¿Oración relativa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La frase desde "de la hiedra" hasta el cierre del paréntesis incluido constituye un complemento de régimen de "agarrándose", núcleo verbal de esa estructura de gerundio que hace de circunstancial de modo del verbo principal "empezó a subir". Dentro de ese complemento de régimen, hay varios componentes coordinados, todos formados por la preposición "de" y una frase nominal como término de la preposición, excepto el último componente de la serie, donde el término "lo que diablos fueran aquellos tallos" es una proposición nominal relativa o relativa libre introducida por "lo que", más o menos equiparable a "cualquier cosa que fueran aquellos tallos ".

La proposición nominal relativa o relativa libre se caracteriza por condensar una proposición sustantiva con una adjetiva. En efecto, observamos en esta oración que la proposición cumple función de término de preposición, pero también podría desempeñar una función típicamente nominal, como la de sujeto: "Lo que diablos fueran aquellos tallos me permitieron comenzar a trepar por la ladera."

El uso del subjuntivo se justifica por el desconocimiento de la especie de los tallos, como si dijéramos:  "de aquellos tallos, cualquiera fuese su nombre ".

Nota: "Él" al inicio de la oración debería omitirse o ser seguido por una coma.

Comment: ¡¡¡te agradezco muchísimo!!! : )